# Editing breadcrumb trail text in d3js Sunburst Example

Tags: d3.js, breadcrumbs, sunburst-diagram

I am creating an infographic based on the d3js Sunburst diagram. Here is a link to what I have so far:
http://www.dinaveprinsky.com/?p=1045

I need to change the output on the breadcrumb trail for ONLY the 4 interior circle pieces (2000, 2005, 2010, 2015) to a string of text that I enter.

Basically I need it to say that in 2010 there were 68 participants in the art fair, etc. (P.S. the numbers I was given for male and female participants in 2010 add up to 67 but I need it to say 68)

Here is a picture of what I am looking for:
[desired end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ8bU.jpg)

The rest of the breadcrumb trail output should remain as is - showing percentages of the pie.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this goes live tomorrow morning!

Here is my code:

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 550;
var height = 550;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// make `colors` an ordinal scale
 var colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#3182bd","#ff7f0e","#aec7e8","#dbdb8d","#ffbb78","#f7b6d2", "#ff9896","#c5b0d5","#c49c94","#c7c7c7","#7f7f7f","#ff9896", "#17becf","#9467bd","#9edae5","#bcbd22","#636363","#969696", "#bdbdbd","#d9d9d9"]);

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

// Use d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.

//var text = getText();
//var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
//var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
var json = getData();
createVisualization(json);

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();

  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

    var uniqueNames = (function(a) {
        var output = [];
        a.forEach(function(d) {
            if (output.indexOf(d.name) === -1) {
                output.push(d.name);
            }
        });
        return output;
    })(nodes);

  // set domain of colors scale based on data
  colors.domain(uniqueNames);

  // make sure this is done after setting the domain
  drawLegend();


  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.name); })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("stroke", "#fff")
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 }

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.name); });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", colors.domain().length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(colors.domain())
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d); });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how 
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
}


function getData() {
    return {
 "name": "participants",
  "children": [
                   {"name": "2015",
                         "children": [
                          {"name": "male",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 5},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 24},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 12},
                                  {"name": "50s", "size": 7},
                                  {"name": "60s", "size": 9},
                                  {"name": "70s", "size": 4},
                                  {"name": "80s", "size": 4},
                                  {"name": "deceased", "size": 12}
                                  ]
                  },
                         {"name": "female",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 8},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 14},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 7},
                                  {"name": "50s", "size": 9},
                                  {"name": "60s", "size": 8},
                                  {"name": "70s", "size": 3},
                                  {"name": "80s", "size": 3},
                                  {"name": "deceased", "size": 3}
                                  ]
                   }
                   ]


                   },




                   {"name": "2010",
                       "children": [
                          {"name": "male",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 5},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 26},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 2}

                                  ]
                  },
                         {"name": "female",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 11},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 20},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 3}

                                  ]
                   }
                   ]


                   },


                   {"name": "2005",

                     "children": [
                          {"name": "male",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 25},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 64},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 11},
                                  {"name": "50s", "size": 1},
                                  {"name": "age n/a", "size": 3}
                                  ]
                  },
                         {"name": "female",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 8},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 43},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 4},
                                  {"name": "age n/a", "size": 4}
                                  ]
                   }
                   ]

                   },

                   {"name": "2000",
                   "children": [
                          {"name": "male",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 12},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 51},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 15},
                                  {"name": "60s", "size": 1},
                                  {"name": "age n/a", "size": 6}
                                  ]
                  },
                         {"name": "female",
                              "children": [
                                  {"name": "20s",  "size": 6},
                                  {"name": "30s", "size": 33},
                                  {"name": "40s", "size": 11},
                                  {"name": "age n/a", "size": 10}
                                  ]
                   }
                   ]

                   }
                   ]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this put a display text in your JSON
Currently your JSON is like this:

```
 {
                "name": "2000",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "male",
                        "children": [{
                        "name": "20s",
                            "size": 12
                    }, { ....
```

So if i want to add my own display text add another key value **("displayText": "21 participants")** like below:

```
 {
                "name": "2000",
                "displayText": "21 participants",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "male",
                        "children": [{
                        "name": "20s",
                            "size": 12
                    }, {
```

This will ensure that for *name:2000* you will get this text for display.
You can add the above to which ever node you wish to see a display text entered by you.

Now in the code part mouseover function do

```
function mouseover(d) {
    if (!d.displayText) {
        var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
        var percentageString = percentage + "%";
        if (percentage < 0.1) {
            percentageString = "< 0.1%";
        }
    } else { //handeling our key value passed for display
        percentageString = d.displayText;
    }
```

Last change :) inside your `function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString)` make the endlabel left aligned like

```
d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
        .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
        .attr("y", b.h / 2)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")//make it left aalligned
        .text(percentageString);
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/49bd9cvw/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much again! You are AMAZING!!! Here is a link to the finished graphic up on www.ARTnews.com: http://www.artnews.com/2015/10/10/greater-new-york-graphics/